# Can't find bundle for base name org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextArea, locale sv_SE

Tags: java, swing, locale, rsyntaxtextarea

I am trying out an example for RSyntaxTextArea found here

http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/examples/example1.php

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import org.fife.ui.rtextarea.*;
import org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.*;

    /**
     * A simple example showing how to use RSyntaxTextArea to add Java syntax
     * highlighting to a Swing application.<p>
     * 
     * This example uses RSyntaxTextArea 2.0.1.<p>
     * 
     * Project Home: http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea<br>
     * Downloads: https://sourceforge.net/projects/rsyntaxtextarea
     */
    public class TextEditorDemo extends JFrame {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       public TextEditorDemo() {

          JPanel cp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

          RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea(20, 60);
          textArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_JAVA);
          textArea.setCodeFoldingEnabled(true);
          textArea.setAntiAliasingEnabled(true);
          RTextScrollPane sp = new RTextScrollPane(textArea);
          sp.setFoldIndicatorEnabled(true);
          cp.add(sp);

          setContentPane(cp);
          setTitle("Text Editor Demo");
          setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          pack();
          setLocationRelativeTo(null);

       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          // Start all Swing applications on the EDT.
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                new TextEditorDemo().setVisible(true);
             }
          });
       }
    }
```

this exception is thrown

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextAreaUI.<clinit>(RSyntaxTextAreaUI.java:37)
    at org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextArea.createRTextAreaUI(RSyntaxTextArea.java:723)
    at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextAreaBase.init(RTextAreaBase.java:630)
    at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextArea.init(RTextArea.java:854)
    at org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextArea.init(RSyntaxTextArea.java:1784)
    at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextAreaBase.<init>(RTextAreaBase.java:117)
    at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextArea.<init>(RTextArea.java:215)
    at org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextArea.<init>(RSyntaxTextArea.java:363)
    at TextEditorDemo.<init>(TextEditorDemo.java:24)
    at TextEditorDemo$1.run(TextEditorDemo.java:44)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextArea, locale sv_SE
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
    at org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextAreaEditorKit.<clinit>(RSyntaxTextAreaEditorKit.java:76)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextArea cannot be cast to ResourceBundle
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(Unknown Source)
    ... 27 more
```

What is wrong here, any ideas how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to the problem already,

instead of copying the source for RSyntaxTextArea into my eclipse project's src folder, I build the rsyntaxtextarea.jar file with ANT and included this jar file in my eclipse projects java build path instead.